# Changing ENV variables in Heroku doesn't change them in Phoenix application

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix 1.2 application running on Heroku, with an ENV variable that sets the email addresses I wish to send email to.

When I change the environment variable's value, it doesn't seem to take; Only after I make a PR and redeploy does the new change seem to take.

This makes it seem like I need to "reload" the code or memory somehow. Thus, 2 questions:

1. Why is this occurring?
2. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: What buildpacks are you using? Is your code using `System.get_env/1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're setting your env values in `config` files and using `Application.get_env` to access them in your application.

---

Elixir applications are compiled, not interpreted. When you deploy your application to heroku, it compiles it with the available Environment Variables and they become hardcoded in to the app. So, even restarting the application would not work; it needs to be recompiled with the new environment variables.

**Here are a few solutions:**

- You can use [`RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS=true`](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/05/how-to-config-environment-variables-with-elixir-and-exrm/) if you're using `Exrm` to build releases;
- Use [`System.get_env`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#get_env/1) for getting ENV variables instead, but this won't work unless the application is restarted after changing the environment configuration;
- Use a [simple wrapper module](https://gist.github.com/bitwalker/a4f73b33aea43951fe19b242d06da7b9) that lets you use environment configurations by specifying them like `{:system, "MY_VARIABLE"}` in `config.exs`;
- Or use an existing package like [`Confex`](https://github.com/Nebo15/confex) or [`Conform`](https://github.com/bitwalker/conform) to manage your configurations

Comment: Could I also do `IEx.Helpers.recompile` inside `iex` console and recompile the app after I change the ENV vars?

Comment: I don't believe so. Because when you execute a program, it receives a "copy" of your shell and env vars along with it (or at least that's what I understand).